# Drill won’t go through vanity to install knobs

Tags: bathroom, wood

I’ve tried two different drill bits but they just won’t go through the vanity so I can add knobs. Any idea why it won’t work?

Comment: You sure you've got the drill set to run 'forwards' and not 'backwards'?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What is the vanity made of? Would you add a picture to your question?

Comment: If the front of the drawer is attached to the box of the drawer with screws you may be hitting the screw that is holding the drawer front or face to the box.  Look inside the drawer to see if the screws are in line with where you are drilling.

Comment: You need to drill in forward at fast speed